# Como exibir um jPanel quando posiciono o mouse sobre certa região?

Tags: java, netbeans, posição-do-cursor

Olá, eu gostaria de saber como que posso criar um algoritmo em Java para exibir um certo Painel dentro do meu Form JFrame, assim que o usuário posicionar o cursor do mouse em cima de uma certa região pré-programada, que será um canto especifico do próprio Form JFrame!

Answer (score 1):

Isso daqui te ajuda? Explicações nos comentários do código.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class MouseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(MouseTest::seguir);
    }

    private static void seguir() {
        // 1. Cria a JFrame.
        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Isto é uma tela");
        tela.setResizable(true);
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        // 2. Cria a JPanel que irá aparecer. Desenha algo dentro dele para ficar bem visível.
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                char[] t = "Olá, eu sou o JPanel!".toCharArray();
                g2.drawChars(t, 0, t.length, 30, 10);
            }
        };
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 30));
        tela.add(panel);
        panel.setVisible(false); // Inicialmente invisível.

        // 3. Faz com que ao passar o mouse perto do canto inferior direito da tela, a JPanel apareça.
        // O segredo é adionar um MouseMotionListener.
        Container content = tela.getContentPane();
        tela.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getX() > content.getWidth() * 0.9 && e.getY() > content.getHeight() * 0.9) panel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        // 4. Mostra a tela.
        tela.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        tela.pack();
        tela.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Feito com java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Este efeito que você procura alcançar é mais fácil de implementar usando o JavaFx  pois, nele você pode usar `CSS` no front-end. No `CSS` basta você usar a propriedade `hover` que é super fácil e não tens que usar código Java.